# I want to declare multiple integer values into variable@XYZId with out declaring a VariableTable and inserting multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @XYZId Int
Select @XYZId = ABCId from ABCTable where ABCId in (1,9,18,27)
Select @XYXId
```

--output: 27
--Expected output: All Id's

```
1
9
18
27
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You seem to want to assign a value to an integer.  But somehow you want a list of values to be assigned?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. Why would you expect this to work without declaring it as a table variable? And why do you want to avoid that? Clearly the result of your query is a result set, not a single integer. Use the right tool for the job. In this case, that's a table variable. If you have a specific, valid reason for wanting to avoid table variables, please state it, because I can't think of one, and in any case it's hard to see how you could write your code successfully without using one.

Comment: A single integer variable can't hold more than a single integer. You need to declare a table variable (or a temp table, depending on your requirements) and select your data into it. You can select more than one value at a time using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` or `SELECT INTO ...` syntax.

Comment: Variables, apart from Table Variables, are Scalar. They can hold 1 value, and only 1 value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a table variable, then use the correct syntax:

```
declare @XYZIds table (id Int);

insert into @XYZIds (id)
    select ABCId
    from ABCTable where ABCId in (1, 9, 18, 27);
```